# PRAW - 500 HTTP Response error

Tags: python-3.x, praw, discord.py

So, I'm hosting a discord.py bot on Heroku, and I'm trying to use PRAW to take a random submission from the hot section of the subreddit.

```
if message.content.startswith("~reddit"):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("VaporwaveAesthetics")
    await message.channel.send(subreddit.title)
    s = []
    for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=75):
        s.append(submission)
    x = randint(0,74)
    s = s[x]
    e = discord.Embed(title=s.title,
                      url=s.url,
                      description=s)
    await message.channel.send(embed=e)
```

When it gets to the `reddit.subreddit("VaporwaveAesthetics")` part, I guess the problem is there because when I try to send the title of the subreddit it throws the error.
By the way, for the Heroku hosting I'm using the lastest version of PRAW (6.0.0.dev0), and the discord.py rewrite (1.0.0a).

Here's the error that I'm getting: [Error.](https://pastebin.com/b8WFtDx1)

Comment: Please share the error you're getting.

Comment: Alright, one sec - sorry. Since I'm getting the logs from the command line it will be hard to copy.

Comment: Edited the post with the error @PatrickHaugh

Comment: It doesn't look like [`Subreddit`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html) objects have a `Subreddit.title` attribute.  Maybe try `subreddit.display_name` instead?

Comment: Hmmm... the Quick Start section of the docs imply otherwise. Gotta try changing it tho, thanks.

Comment: You should put the error in the question body instead of on another website.

Comment: does this occur every time you try to send the subreddit title or only occasionally? HTTP 500 means an internal server error which is out of your control. If it's only occasionally you should use a try-except.

Answer (score 0):

That isin't really your fault nor Heroku fault (I Think), 500 Error Code means [Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500#:%7E:text=The%20HyperText%20Transfer%20Protocol%20).
I Suggest you keep trying your code OR use `Try` - `Except`, if you got a 404 code response, that means you inputed a subreddit that dosen't exist.
[List of HTTP Response and what does they mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)